# IdentityServer4 QuickStart Register Issue

Tags: identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

I have ASP.NET Core application with IdentityServer4 using ASP.NET Core Identity (based on excellent quickstart).
http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/6_aspnet_identity.html
In the walkthrough blog they talk about navigating to localhost:5000/Account/Register to create a new user in the Identity db.
When i navigate to that url i get a white page. Furthermore I don't have a Register.cshmtl page or a Register route or anything with the term Register in it.

Did i get the wrong branch? because i am on the release and using core 2.0

I'm new at this and apologize if i'm missing something obvious.
I have run the dotnet ef command but can't see a db anywhere I look - like in sql express or LocalDb.
I am running the Identity server project out of vs17 on port 5000

If i run the MvcClient project I see the home page with the Secure link. If i click that i am directed to the IS4 instance but alice nor bob login will work. (invalid us/pw).
And i can see in the logs that alice and bob users are not being created in-memory

Comment: Give a link to the quickstart you are trying to implement.

Comment: The Quickstart chapters mostly build on the earlier chapters, did you do the earlier ones as well? Do you get the IdentityServer4 logo when you navigate to the localhost:5000 default page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably got this by now, but it might interest someone else.

The [Quickstart UI repository](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI) is not a direct implementation of the tutorials in the IdentityServer4 docs. If you follow the docs, you will first create a new ASP.NET Core MVC application with *Individual User Accounts* authentication, and that template will create the registration page.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is about routing. With [scaffolding Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) and specifying routing Your problem will be resolved.

> To maintain full control of the Identity UI, run the Identity
>   scaffolder and select Override all files.

replace

```
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

with

```
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.AllowAreas = true;
        options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Identity", "/Account/Manage");
        options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaPage("Identity", "/Account/Logout");
    });

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = $"/Identity/Account/Login";
    options.LogoutPath = $"/Identity/Account/Logout";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = $"/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
});

// using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
```

Now you can access to Register account page:
**http://localhost:5000/Identity/Account/Register**

You also can also change default route like what you want (localhost:5000/Account/Register) for this purpose check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52079620/3242314)