# How to customize URL of webpage in Asp.NET Core Identity UI 3.0.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity, .net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.0

I am using .NET Core 3.0.100, Blazor Server web-app, has these packages of Identity

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="3.0.0" />
```

I go to Login page by go to (for example, use port `5011`)

```
https://localhost:5011/Identity/Account/Login
```

I go to Register page by

```
https://localhost:5011/Identity/Account/Register
```

I want change to

```
https://localhost:5011/login
https://localhost:5011/register
```

How to to this?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50682108/change-routing-in-asp-net-core-identity-ui/50682681). There's a few answers with suggestions for how to do this and an answer (mine) that explains some of the reasoning behind what you're describing.

Comment: thanks @KirkLarkin . Can I use trick for alias `/login` to `/Identity/Account/Login` ?

Comment: It should work if you take [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52079620/2630078) and update the call to `Remove` to use `"Identity/Account"`.

Comment: I don't understand your idea in the first section of the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/50682681/3728901 Please at more detail about create URL aliasing.

Comment: _Why_ do you want to change the URLs? That might help with deciding on the best solution to use.

Comment: After your comment, I knew that I can use either **aliasing**, also **change URL directly**.

Comment: There's a page in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-3.0) that talks about rewriting/redirecting that might help.